# Why is transfer learning taking same time as training from scratch ResNet18?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm using a custom trained model based of ResNet18 to learn just the last two layers of the model. Issue is that time to train the last two layers is same as it is taking to train the complete model from scratch.

In the custom model, fc layer of Resnet18 is dropped and two fc layers are added: 
self.l1 = nn.Linear(512, 512) 
self.l2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)

**Model Class**

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models
import torch
from collections import OrderedDict

class ResNetSimCLR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, out_dim):
        super(ResNetSimCLR, self).__init__()
    
        weights_path = r"model-v1.pth"
        num_ftrs = 512
        
        resnet = models.resnet18(pretrained=False, norm_layer=nn.InstanceNorm2d)
        num_ftrs = resnet.fc.in_features

        features = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-1])
        self.features = self._load_weights(features, weights_path)

        for param in self.features.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False

        # projection MLP
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_ftrs)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, int(out_dim))


    def _load_weights(self, model, weights_path):
        custom_weights = torch.load(weights_path)
        new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
        for k, v in custom_weights.items():
            if 'module.' in k:
                k = k.replace('module.', '')
            if 'features' in k:
                k = k.replace('features.', '')
            else:
                # skipping adding the weights related to l1 & l2 as these I want to learn
                continue
            new_state_dict[k]=v

        # Assign the custom weights to the model's parameters
        model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
        print('Weights Loaded Successfully')
        return model

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.features(x)
        h = h.squeeze()

        x = self.l1(h)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.l2(x)
        return h, x
```

**Train Class**

```
import torch
from models.resnet_simclr import ResNetSimCLR
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import torch.nn.functional as F
from loss.nt_xent import NTXentLoss
import os
import shutil
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm

apex_support = False
try:
    sys.path.append('./apex')
    from apex import amp

    apex_support = True
except:
    print("Please install apex for mixed precision training from: https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex")
    apex_support = False

import numpy as np

torch.manual_seed(0)


def _save_config_file(model_checkpoints_folder):
    if not os.path.exists(model_checkpoints_folder):
        os.makedirs(model_checkpoints_folder)
        shutil.copy('./config.yaml', os.path.join(model_checkpoints_folder, 'config.yaml'))


class SimCLR(object):

    def __init__(self, dataset, config):
        self.config = config
        self.device = self._get_device()
        self.writer = SummaryWriter()
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.nt_xent_criterion = NTXentLoss(self.device, config['batch_size'], **config['loss'])

    def _get_device(self):
        device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
        print("Running on:", device)
        return device

    def _step(self, model, xis, xjs, n_iter):

        # get the representations and the projections
        ris, zis = model(xis)  # [N,C]

        # get the representations and the projections
        rjs, zjs = model(xjs)  # [N,C]

        # normalize projection feature vectors
        zis = F.normalize(zis, dim=1)
        zjs = F.normalize(zjs, dim=1)

        loss = self.nt_xent_criterion(zis, zjs)
        return loss

    def train(self):
        train_loader, valid_loader = self.dataset.get_data_loaders()

        model = ResNetSimCLR(self.config["model"]['out_dim'])
        if self.config['n_gpu'] > 1:
            device_n = len(eval(self.config['gpu_ids']))
            model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=range(device_n))
        model = model.to(self.device)
            
        layers_to_optimize = list(model.l1.parameters()) + list(model.l2. 
        parameters())
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(layers_to_optimize, 1e-5, weight_decay=eval(self.config['weight_decay']))
        
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=self.config['epochs'], eta_min=0,
                                                               last_epoch=-1)
        

        if apex_support and self.config['fp16_precision']:
            model, optimizer = amp.initialize(model, optimizer,
                                              opt_level='O2',
                                              keep_batchnorm_fp32=True)

        model_checkpoints_folder = os.path.join(self.writer.log_dir, 'checkpoints')

        # save config file
        _save_config_file(model_checkpoints_folder)

        n_iter = 0
        valid_n_iter = 0
        best_valid_loss = np.inf

        for epoch_counter in tqdm(range(self.config['epochs'])):
            for (xis, xjs) in tqdm(train_loader):
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                xis = xis.to(self.device)
                xjs = xjs.to(self.device)

                loss = self._step(model, xis, xjs, n_iter)

                if n_iter % self.config['log_every_n_steps'] == 0:
                    self.writer.add_scalar('train_loss', loss, global_step=n_iter)

                if apex_support and self.config['fp16_precision']:
                    with amp.scale_loss(loss, optimizer) as scaled_loss:
                        scaled_loss.backward()
                else:
                    loss.backward()

                optimizer.step()
                n_iter += 1

            # validate the model if requested
            if epoch_counter % self.config['eval_every_n_epochs'] == 0:
                valid_loss = self._validate(model, valid_loader)
                if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
                    # save the model weights
                    best_valid_loss = valid_loss
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(model_checkpoints_folder, 'model.pth'))
                    print('saved')

                self.writer.add_scalar('validation_loss', valid_loss, global_step=valid_n_iter)
                valid_n_iter += 1

            # warmup for the first 10 epochs
            if epoch_counter >= 10:
                scheduler.step()
            self.writer.add_scalar('cosine_lr_decay', scheduler.get_lr()[0], global_step=n_iter)

    def _validate(self, model, valid_loader):

        # validation steps
        with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval()

            valid_loss = 0.0
            counter = 0
            for (xis, xjs) in valid_loader:
                xis = xis.to(self.device)
                xjs = xjs.to(self.device)

                loss = self._step(model, xis, xjs, counter)
                valid_loss += loss.item()
                counter += 1
            valid_loss /= counter
        model.train()
        return valid_loss
```

**Data loader class**

```
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from data_aug.gaussian_blur import GaussianBlur
from torchvision import datasets
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io, img_as_ubyte

np.random.seed(0)

class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform=None):
        self.files_list = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.transform = transform
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files_list)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        temp_path = self.files_list.iloc[idx, 0]
        img = Image.open(temp_path)
        img = transforms.functional.to_tensor(img)
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(img)
        return sample

class ToPIL(object):
    def __call__(self, sample):
        img = sample
        img = transforms.functional.to_pil_image(img)
        return img 

class DataSetWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, batch_size, num_workers, valid_size, input_shape, s):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.valid_size = valid_size
        self.s = s
        self.input_shape = eval(input_shape)

    def get_data_loaders(self):
        data_augment = self._get_simclr_pipeline_transform()
        train_dataset = Dataset(csv_file='all_patches.csv', transform=SimCLRDataTransform(data_augment))
        train_loader, valid_loader = self.get_train_validation_data_loaders(train_dataset)
        return train_loader, valid_loader

    def _get_simclr_pipeline_transform(self):
        # get a set of data augmentation transformations as described in the SimCLR paper.
        color_jitter = transforms.ColorJitter(0.8 * self.s, 0.8 * self.s, 0.8 * self.s, 0.2 * self.s)
        data_transforms = transforms.Compose([ToPIL(),
                                              transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=self.input_shape[0]),
                                              transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                              transforms.RandomApply([color_jitter], p=0.8),
                                              transforms.RandomGrayscale(p=0.2),
                                              GaussianBlur(kernel_size=int(0.06 * self.input_shape[0])),
                                              transforms.ToTensor()])
        return data_transforms

    def get_train_validation_data_loaders(self, train_dataset):
        # obtain training indices that will be used for validation
        num_train = len(train_dataset)
        indices = list(range(num_train))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)

        split = int(np.floor(self.valid_size * num_train))
        train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]

        # define samplers for obtaining training and validation batches
        train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
        valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)

        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, sampler=train_sampler,
                                  num_workers=self.num_workers, drop_last=True, shuffle=False)
        valid_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler,
                                  num_workers=self.num_workers, drop_last=True)
        return train_loader, valid_loader


class SimCLRDataTransform(object):
    def __init__(self, transform):
        self.transform = transform

    def __call__(self, sample):
        xi = self.transform(sample)
        xj = self.transform(sample)
        return xi, xj
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a model issue? You could be bottlenecked on loading from disk or transforming data.

Comment: If that is the case how do I resolve it?